# jQuery .get response as javascript/html

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bnr').each(function() {
        var group = jQuery(this).attr('adgroup');
        var obj = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.get("http://www.example.com/ads.php",
    { 'adGroup': group },
    function( response ) {
            obj.html( response );
        }
    );
    })
});
```

I'm trying to load ads using jQuery. The ads.php return affiliates code. Problem is when the return response is javascript. All works only if response is html. Using eval() do not work or i'm missing something.
response example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adserving.unibet.com/ad.aspx?pid=1234&pbg=123">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load dynamic content from a url

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bnr').each(function() {
        var group = jQuery(this).attr('adgroup');
        var obj = jQuery(this);

        obj.load("http://www.example.com/ads.php", { 'adGroup': group })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way

```
 jQuery('.bnr').each(function() {
        var group = jQuery(this).attr('adgroup');
        var obj = jQuery(this);

       $.ajax({
           url: 'http://www.example.com/ads.php',
           data: { 'adGroup': group },
           dataType: "text/html", // this will make sure that your response is html 
           success: function(data){
             obj.html( data );
           }
       });
});
```